# Python: how to write a variable number of lists to a line of a new file

Tags: python, list

I have an output of which each line contains one list, each list contains one word of a sentence after hyphenation.
It looks something like this:

```
['I']
['am']
['a']
['man.']
['I']
['would']
['like']
['to']
['find']
['a']
['so','lu','tion.'] 
(let's say it's hyphenated like this, I'm not a native English speaker)

etc.
```

Now, what I'd like to do is write this output to a new .txt file, but each sentence (sentence ends when item in list contains a point) has to be written to a newline. I'd like to have following result written to this .txt file:

```
I am a man.
I would like to find a so,lu,tion.
etc.
```

The coding that precedes all this is the following:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if h_en.syllables(word)!=[]:
                h_en.syllables (word)
            else:
                print ([word])
```

The result I want is a file which contains a sentence at each line.
Each word of a sentence is represented by it's hyphenated version.

Any suggestions?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please show us the program which generates the output

Comment: How do you mean? It is Python 3.

Comment: Your actual python program which generates the output you mentioned in the question. If you could show us that, probably we would be able to help you fix that.

Comment: ok, i hope it's more clear in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Something basic like this seems to answer your need:

```
def write_sentences(filename, *word_lists):
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
    sentence = []
    for word_list in word_lists:
      word = ",".join(word_list) ##last edit
      sentence.append(word)
      if word.endswith("."):
        f.write(" ".join(sentence))
        f.write("\n")
        sentence = []
```

Feed the `write_sentences` function with the output filename, then each of your word
lists as arguments. If you have a list of word lists (e.g `[['I'], ['am'], ...]`), you can use `*` when calling
the function to pass everything.

**EDIT**: changed to make it work with the latest edit of the answer (with multiple words in the word lists)

Comment: Since the hypenathion can cause the word_list to have more elements than just one, I adapted your code a bit:
`def write_sentences(filename, *word_lists):
 with open(filename, "w") as f:
  sentence = []
  for word_list in word_lists:
   x=(len(word_list)-len(word_list))
   y=(len(word_list)-1)
   word = word_list[x:y]
   sentence.append(word)
   if (".")in word:
    f.write(" ".join(sentence))
    f.write("\n")
    sentence = []`
However, when I feed the `write_sentences` function with the required specifications, nothing is being written to the file. Do I overlook something?

Comment: I edited the answer to try to help with your last example in the question. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

This short regex does what you want when it is compiled in MULTILINE mode:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("\[([a-zA-Z\s]*\.?)\]$",re.MULTILINE)`
>>> a = regex.findall(string)
>>> a
[u'I', u'am', u'a man.', u'I', u'would like', u'to find', u'a solution.']
```

Now you just manipulate the list until you get your wanted result. An example follows, but there are more ways to do it:

```
>>> b = ' '.join(a)
>>> b
'I am a real man. I want a solution.'
>>> c = re.sub('\.','.\n',b)
>>> print(c)
'I am a real man.'
' I want a solution.'
>>> with open("result.txt", "wt") as f:
        f.write(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = [['I'],['am'],['a'],['man.'],['I'],['would'],['like'],['to'],['find'],['a'],['so','lu','tion.']]

text = "".join(
    "".join(item) + ("\n" if item[-1].endswith(".") else " ") 
        for item in words)

with open("out.txt", "wt") as f:
    f.write(text)
```